# Samsung Galaxy S3 w Android version 4.1.2 won't accept input

Tags: android

Two testers reported that they could not enter data into the text box, of my mobile app (android).  They are both using a Samsung Galaxy S3.  The app is an html/css/jquery native app.  It uses cordova-1.9.0.jar and android-support-v4.jar

I am able to reproduce the issue in an android emulator. See attached picture below for its specs. Android version 4.1.2   ARM processor;

When I click in the input box, the box shows that it has the focus, the keyboard pops up, and when I click on a letter or number the key lights up like it should; but no characters are entered into the input box.

Here's the code for the input box

```
    <input name="boxZipcode" placeholder="Enter Zipcode" data-theme="b"
```

id="boxZipcode"  type="tel"  />

I get the same non-results whether its a numbers-only keyboard, or a full keyboard.

What do I need to change to make the input boxes accept input?  Thanks.

r[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem went away when I upgraded from cordova 1.9.0 to cordova 2.5.0

The android guy's comment (#13) at [this issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=17508) at android issues says that a similar problem  "involved a race condition with the GC and weak references"

Also, fyi, I had warnings in LogCat indicating a race condition, like.

skipped 31 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
and 
IInputConnectionWrapper beginBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection

Answer (score 1):

the fix is look for the following CSS style

```
 -webkit-user-select: none;
```

Just remove this line and you can type happily in the input elements!